# Tips on making dry erase squeeks

Tags: foley

Looking for a few tips on props to use to make the dry erase marker squeek sound.  Looking for something that projects volume a little more and is more controllable than an actual dry erase marker.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: i was wondering too..

Comment: Hi Michael, what did you end up doing? Curious!

Comment: @Arnoud  In my experiments and using the suggestions I have found a couple of things that seem to work.  Going to the studio to record them this week and see how they end up working with the picture cut that just got done today.  I have found that wetting a Cue Tip and using that instead of my finger provides a sound a bit closer and very controllable.

Answer (score 3):

Hi, I've recently recorded 10 different dry erase pens and had great succes with a close mic'ed mkh50 into a RME Fireface UC. Mic was about 10 cm away from the board which was cheap. Be very quiet (breathing and movement) and take care to keep the distance steady for all recordings. You don't have to do exactly what I did,  experiment with the distance and find what works best for you. And practice some gestures before the recording, it helps getting into the sound and character.

Oh and I recorded for almost 2 hours with a short break, be prepared to edit a lot of material if you need more than 10 seconds of pen squeeks.

I'll upload a sample in a bit, so you can listen to it.

here's the link:

http://soundcloud.com/de-auditieve-dienst/dry-erase-markers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you could use to emulate that sound without actually recording it. If i was you i would close mic an eraser bring used then compress and level it to a louder volume. The only other thing i can suggest is to make a squeaky synth sound by resonating the top harmonics of a synth patch and using envelopes on a resonant filter to try and get close to the timbre of the real thing.

Comment: @emotekon not looking for something synth based, but foley props I guess.  The closest thing I have managed is using a drum head and some water on my fingers to achieve a lower squeek and then pitching it up in post.  Going to try balloons and other plastics tommorow.  The problem with the marker and dry erase board itself is it just is not creating the sound I want to go with the picture of it happening.

Answer (score 1):

i have got similarish squeaky sounds by sliding my fingers over tiles and glass.  It probably isn't louder than a pen on a white board but could give you more control.

Comment: @Haydn Yes consistency and control are what I am looking for.  Tried this and good some good results

Answer (score 1):

Slightly damp chamois cloths on dry glass or mirrors can work quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with slightly wet paper towel wrapped around my finger, and rubbing a pane of glass.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but maybe make a piezo transducer, and tape it to the board, or a sheet of glass. Then tried tried fingers, pens, rubbers etc. The piezo might be a bit intense on it's own though.

Answer (score 0):

Dry skin against the grain on a wood floor may achieve an over the top squeak with more control

Answer (score 0):

Try rubbing your theeth with your finger, after you brushed them with a thick toothpaste.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a few different sizes of markers/ felt tip pens and let them dry out for a few days.  The drier, more solid tips (using a white board) should create more friction = louder sound.  This makes sense in my head, not sure if would work or not.

Comment: hi dan, actually, i've tried older pens and learned that the less liquid/ink in them, the softer the sound would be. i had to press really hard to get a distinct squeek sound. in the end i used a combination of fresh and semi-fresh pens and just searched for the right angle for the pens tip on the whiteboard.